# I want to split string by number and symbol "." in java

Tags: java

I need to split the String by `numbers` and  `.` symbol.
 My String is

```
"Nagapur82. Nanavade83. Nandur84. Nandurkichi Wadi85."
```

and I want Array of like

```
[ "Nagapur", "Nanavade", "Nandur", "Nandurkichi Wadi"]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Also check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. Show us what you have tried so far and what the problems are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String s = "Nagapur82. Nanavade83. Nandur84. Nandurkichi Wadi85.";

        s = s.replace(" ", "");
        s = s.replace(".", "");
        String[] s2 = s.split("[0-9]+");
```

This may work

Answer (score 0):

Let's implement something manually first, just for fun.

First, you count the number of substrings:

```
int count = 0; //Number of elements
boolean wasSeparator = true;

for (int index = 0; index < s.length(); index++) {
    boolean isSeparator = (((Character.isDigit(s.charAt(index))) || (s.charAt(index) == '.')));
    if (wasSeparator && (!isSeparator) {
        count++;
    }
    wasSeparator = isSeparator;
}
```

`count` represents the length of your array. Now compute the substrings into an array of strings:

```
String[] elements = [];
int itemIndex = 0;
int start = -1;
int end = -1;
for (int index = 0; index < s.length; index++) {
    boolean isSeparator = (((Character.isDigit(s.charAt(index))) || (s.charAt(index) == '.')));
    if (isSeparator) {
        if (start >= 0) {
            end = index;
            elements[itemIndex++] = s.substring(start, end);
            start = -1;
            end = -1;
        }
    } else {
        if (start == -1) start = index;
    }
}
if (start >= 0) elements[itemIndex++] = s.substring(start);
```

Of course, you can use `split`:

```
String[] result = s.split(yourregex);
```

and your regex is that it's digit or dot. Your regular expression will contain \d and .

Your regex here is `(\d|\.)+`, so try

```
String[] result = s.split((\d|\.)+);
```